# Reusing a character class in a regular expression

Tags: regex, hardcoded, character-class

In order to keep a regular expression more brief, is there a shorthand way to refer to a character class that occurs earlier in the same regular expression?

**Example**

Is there a way to shorten the following:

`[acegikmoqstz@#&].*[acegikmoqstz@#&].*[acegikmoqstz@#&]`

Comment: Hmm... What programming language are you working with?

Comment: Dynamically creating the regex with a variable might be your best bet.  For example in Python you could do `cc = r'[acegikmoqstz@#&]'; regex = r'{0}.*{0}.*{0}'.format(cc)`.

Comment: In most programming languages, there isn't; but in languages where regexps are strings, you can get the same effect by building your regexp out of previously defined strings.

Comment: argh, like @F.J _just_ said :-)

Comment: @NoBrainer Java, but I'm also interested as to whether or not this can be done only with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that regex features are dependant on the language being used.

With Java, you can do this:

```
[acegikmoqstz@#&](?:.*[acegikmoqstz@#&]){2}
```

But that's all, with java you can't refer to named subpattern.

With PHP you can do that:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<a>[acegikmoqstz@#&]))\g<a>(?:.*\g<a>){2}
```