# Custom character class in C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

Is there any way to define custom character class in C# regex?

In flex it is done in very obvious way:

```
DIGIT    [0-9]
%%
{DIGIT}+    {printf( "An integer: %s (%d)\n", yytext, atoi( yytext ) );}
```

http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Simple-Examples.html#Simple-Examples

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109719/145999), in PHP defining a custom character class works like this:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<a>[acegikmoqstz@#&]))\g<a>(?:.*\g<a>){2}
```

Is there a way to achieve this result in c#, without repeating the full character class definition each time it is used?

Comment: @Rawling: It's same kind of question, but the point is: How to do it (if possible) in C#.

Comment: Reason for my *reopen vote*: The answer in the linked duplicate **does not address c#** at all, it explicitly only deals with Java and PHP. The solutions presented there are not applicable for c# (@Rawling)

Comment: @HugoRune Good point, I thought both the answer were just language-specific versions of string concatenation but the PHP one is doing something special. There is a [C# specific question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204214/regex-reusing-subexpressions) and I expect most answers you attract will be along the same lines.

Comment: @Rawling Yes, I don't think a better solution exists either. But I was googling for this problem, and this question here seemed to be the only applicable result, so a definitive answer here should be useful to future visitors, even if it is a negative one.

Comment: It may be possible to use named blocks and class subtraction to get the same effect, or there may be a named block that already matches the required characters

Comment: Thanks for better version of question @HugoRune

Answer (score 3):

Custom character classes aren't supported in C# but you may be able to use [named blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#CategoryOrBlock) and  [character class subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction) to get a similar effect.

.NET defines [a large number of named block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks)s that correspond to Unicode character categories like math or Greek symbols. There may be a block that already matches your requirements.

Character class subtraction allows you to exclude the characters in one class or block from the characters in a broader class. The syntax is :

```
[ base_group -[ excluded_group ]]
```

The following example, copied from the linked documentation, matches all Unicode characters except whitespace, Greek characters, punctuation and newlines:

```
[\u0000-\uFFFF-[\s\p{P}\p{IsGreek}\x85]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not supported in C#. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you a nice overview of the .NET Regex engine. Note that nothing really stops you from defining variables and using them to construct your Regex string:

```
var digit = "[0-9]";
var regex = new Regex(digit + "[A-Z]");
```